# Does Magic The Gathering work on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: games

Does someone knows if Magic the Gathering works on Ubuntu 23.04?

Comment: Do you mean MTG: Arena? You should probably be very specific about the title.

Comment: And no, I have no clue. If you have Wine and Steam installed, you could maybe test it out?

Comment: [Cockatrice](https://cockatrice.github.io/) does, if MTG doesn't :D